# Difference between INDEX/MATCH in worksheet and in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is driving me absolute mental and I just can't see what the difference is.

In my excel worksheet

```
=INDEX(BE1home[[GF ]];MATCH(TRIM(Sheet4!B10);BE1home[[  2]];0);1)
```

In VBA

```
WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("BE1home").ListColumns("GF ").DataBodyRange, WorksheetFunction.Match(Trim(sq1(i, 1)), Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("BE1home").ListColumns(" 2").DataBodyRange, 0))
```

The excel worksheet formula works but the VBA one doesn't and I just can't figure out why. In VBA I keep getting Subscript out of range.

**Extra info**

sq1(i,1) is the same value as Sheet4!B10. I have to trim it as there is a trailing space.
The list where I'm trying to get the data form is in Sheet3 but the results are in Sheet4.

Comment: You don't need to use `Index` here actually.

Comment: You're missing a bracket at the end of your code line. You should also be more specific with your question - what is happening?

Comment: @Rory, was a typing error when pasting the code. On the actual script the bracket is there. I keep getting error `Subscript out of Range`

Comment: @BigBen Didn't know this. But even without Index it gives the same errors.

Comment: Break up that line in multiple steps to debug further (posted an answer). Sounds like one of the names (`Sheet3`, `BE1home`, etc.) is off. You don't need to use `Index` and can just use `Cells` with the result of the match.

Comment: Your formula suggests that there are two spaces before the 2 in the column header, but your VBA only appears to have one.

Comment: @Rory, removed the spaces. Now I'm getting `Method 'Match' of object 'WorksheetFunction' failed`

Comment: Then it's not finding your lookup value.

Comment: Cleaned all my data, that doesn't seem to be the error

Comment: @Rory, you're so right! Now need to figure this out :-)